# iOS: SetContentOffset for Scrollview doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I have 3 Scrollviews and they should scroll synchron with the other...

But this code doesn't work:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
[rowIdCellScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, contentScrollView.contentOffset.y)];
[headerScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(contentScrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was, that i inited the components in layoutsubviews...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have UIScrollViewDelegate? And set delagate:

```
rowIdCellScrollView.delegate = self;
```

And does this scrollViewDidScroll even call?